# Post on Facebook Wall via Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> I tried to post on facebook wall using below code-

```
function facebook_login() {
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: 'Hello, world!' }, function(status) {
                if (!status || status.error) {
                  console.log('Error occured');
                } else {
                  console.log('Post ID: ' + status.id);
                }
            });
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                var user_profile = JSON.stringify(response);
            });
        }
    },{scope: 'email,publish_actions,user_birthday,offline_access'});
}
```

> But It throw me this error:
>
> **code: 200**
>
> **message: "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"**
>
> **type: "OAuthException"**
>
> I do not understand what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`offline_access` is deprecated since years, and you don´t need it anyway. You only need `publish_actions` for posting, and you need to go through a [review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login) process before it works for any user. Make sure the `publish_actions` permission gets asked for in the authorization popup, and only try with an app admin/developer.

That error message means that you did not authorize correctly with `publish_actions`.

Comment: should I send my app for review to get "publish_actions" permission?

Comment: if you want it to work for all users and not just users with a role in the app, then yes